# Need help making a 3D mesh given co-ordinates of the vertices and vertex indices of each face for 3D Slicer - trimesh python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, 3d, mesh, trimesh

Given the following data:

1. The Cartesian co-ordinates of the vertices in the surface mesh: n vertices x 3
2. The vertex indices of each face in the surface mesh: n faces x 3

I'm trying to export some 3D file that I can readily import to [3D Slicer](https://www.slicer.org/) for registration against a VTK file.

Faces: https://pastebin.com/qWq7aiEs

Vertices: https://pastebin.com/VxsxsdcM

I have been trying various packages/libraries etc. and keep running into various issues. The following issue is using the [Trimesh in Python](https://pythonawesome.com/python-library-for-loading-and-using-triangular-meshes/) and I'm attributing the problem to my poor python ability rather than an issue with the package. I'm open to other solution as well.

I imported the CSV, extracted the arrays then converted to lists to match the example. I wasn't certain how to use the faces data given the example, so I just made a list that matched the length of vertices, not sure if that's right at all.

```
# Example: mesh objects can be created from existing faces and vertex data
mesh = trimesh.Trimesh(vertices=[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]],
                       faces=[[0, 1, 2]])

# My attempt
vertex_x = vertices_csv[:,0]
vertex_y = vertices_csv[:,1]
vertex_z = vertices_csv[:,2]
vertex_x_list = vertex_x.tolist()
vertex_y_list = vertex_y.tolist()
vertex_z_list = vertex_z.tolist()
faces_list_mesh = [i for i in range(len(vertex_x_list))]

mesh = trimesh.Trimesh(vertices=[vertex_x_list, vertex_y_list, vertex_z_list],
...                        faces=[faces_list_mesh])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\trimesh\base.py", line 190, in __init__
    self.process(validate=validate,
  File "C:\...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\trimesh\base.py", line 232, in process
    self.merge_vertices(merge_tex=merge_tex,
  File "C:\...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\trimesh\base.py", line 1123, in merge_vertices
    grouping.merge_vertices(
  File "C:\...\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\trimesh\grouping.py", line 70, in merge_vertices
    referenced[mesh.faces] = True
IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

Any advice how to troubleshoot is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By downloading the data you provided, I coded the following:

```py
import numpy as np
import trimesh

vertices = np.loadtxt("vertices.txt", delimiter=",")
faces = np.loadtxt("faces.txt", delimiter=",") - 1

mesh = trimesh.Trimesh(vertices=vertices, faces=faces)
mesh.export("mesh.stl")
```

So the code does work, however I am not so sure about the correctness of your input data. Vertices are indexed from 0 to `vertex_count - 1`, so in this case `[0, 6500]` That's why I have subtracted `-1` to `faces` since vertices are 0-indexed.
The `faces` array consists of vertex indices, however its maximum index values (after subtracting -1) is 6500 and that's fine, but the minimum is 262. So check your data carefully.

The code above exports the following mesh:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you! I also got similar feedback from package maintainer here: https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh/issues/1646

Ya'll rock